# Any PDF reader that shows grids?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader

I know Acrobat Pro shows grids for PDF files. Is there any other PDF reader that shows grids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDF-XChange-Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) does. Check out the link for more details.

Reference: Read the second last post on this page: http://forums.techarena.in/networking-security/1133795.htm